# Цвет верхней части экрана меняется на зеленый при просмотре сайта

Tags: android, веб-программирование, ios, браузер, iphone

В мобильной версии сайта при входе (android) и прокрутке(iOS) страницы, в верхней части экрана цвет фона меняется на зеленый. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrwKw.jpg)

Проверил iOS на нескольких браузерах. Проблема появляется только на Safari.
Проверил Android на нескольких браузерах. Проблема появляется на yandex браузере и chrome. При этом в chrome в инкогнито строка состояний черная,как и должна быть
В десктоп версии и при эмуляции через devtools такой проблемы не наблюдается.
Доступа к коду я не имею, просто нужно выяснить в чем причина. Это вероятно как-то связано с какими-либо настройками браузера, но пока не смог выяснить с какими именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема появлялась, только если адресная строка в браузере статична. Если она пропадала при скроле вниз, то полосы не было. Выяснили,что  для окрашивания верхней панели браузера, используется  мета-тег theme-color. значение которого #56CC56 (зелёный)